# Check if given string is palindrome c++ iterative method

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, iteration, palindrome

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

string str;
cout << "Enter a string: ";
getline(cin, str);

int length = str.length();
string temp;
int k = 0;
for(int i = length-1; i>=0; i--){
    
    temp[++k] = str[i];
    
}

cout<<temp;
    
return 0;
```

}

Actually, i want to find out whether the given string is a palindrome or not, so i am storing the first string in second one in reverse order , and then will ultimately check whether they are equal or not, but i am unable to print out even the result of temp string

Comment: `temp` is empty. Indexing into it is UB. Use `push_back` instead. Or allocate sufficient space for `temp`.

Comment: Please fix the formatting, in particular add indentation. Also, you don't describe your observations but only an interpretation ("i am unable to..."). Please take the [tour], read [ask] and extract a [mcve] from your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined an empty object of the type std::string

```
string temp;
```

So you may not use the subscript operator with the empty object in the loop.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = length-1; i>=0; i--){
    
    temp[++k] = str[i];
    
}
```

Using your approach you could just write

```
string temp( str.rbegin(), str.rend() );
```

without using a loop.

However to check whether a string is a palindrome there is no need to create an intermediate string.

You could do it in a loop the following way.

```
std::string::size_type i = 0;

for ( auto n = str.length(); i < n / 2 && str[i] == str[n - i - 1]; )
{
    ++i;
}

if ( i == str.length() /2 ) std::cout << str << " is a palindrome\n";
```

Or without the loop and defining one more variable you could write

```
if ( str == std::string( str.rbegin(), str.rend() ) )
{
    std::cout << str << " is a palindrome\n";
}
```